Hibernate generates not correct SQL concerning subqueries with IN clause
Today I ran into an issue with Hibernate 6 and Firebird 4 database which is best demonstrated by the following query:
select * from rdb$relations 
where rdb$relation_id in ((select rdb$relation_id from rdb$relations))

Upon execution I get the following error:

SQL Error [335544652] [21000]: multiple rows in singleton select [SQLState:21000, ISC error code:335544652]

It comes because Firebird internally understands two forms of IN() and handles them differently - the <table subquery> and <scalar subquery>. The use of double parentheses let Firebird interpret the subquery as <scalar subquery> that must have at most one result.
The following (example) query is executed as expected but is not generated by Hibernate 6:
select * from rdb$relations 
where rdb$relation_id in (select rdb$relation_id from rdb$relations)

The problem came into out project after moving from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6. While generating SQL from the Criteria API, Hibernate uses an own implementation of the CriteriaBuilder interface. This implementation handles the IN() constructs by generating an appropriate Predicate instance. In Hibernate 5, there was only the InPredicate implementation. This one handled internally correctly both cases - list of values and subquery. In Hibernate 6, the aforementioned predicate implementation has been replaced with InListPredicate and InSubQueryPredicate. The problem is now that the CriteriaBuilder implementation in Hibernate 6 - SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder - creates the wrong Predicate instance - it creates only InListPredicate which generates double parentheses in the resulting SQL.
The only one workaround that I currently see, but don't really like, is not to use JPA API but Hibernate specific API. So instead of
public Predicate getFilterPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, String name, String filterValue, MatchMode matchMode, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
 Subquery<Customer> subquery = query.subquery(Customer.class);
 Root<Address> from = subquery.from(Address.class);
 subquery.select(from.get("customer"));
 . . . 
 return rootQuery.in(subquery); 
}

use the following
public Predicate getFilterPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, String name, String filterValue, MatchMode matchMode, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
 Subquery<Customer> subquery = query.subquery(Customer.class);
 Root<Address> from = subquery.from(Address.class);
 subquery.select(from.get("customer"));
 . . . 
 return ((NodeBuilder)builder).in(rootQuery, (SqmSubQuery)subquery);
}

Does somebody have a clue how to let Hibernate 6 create and use InSubQueryPredicate in my case while still sticking to standard JPA API?

I think the problem might be that JPA doesn't really define support for IN with a subquery, its API only talks about "a list of values", so it is entirely possible that the behaviour in Hibernate 5 was actually not compliant. I guess you may need to rewrite to an exists with a correlated subquery instead.

I was able to reproduce the problem with this code:
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> q = cb.createQuery();
Root<Customer> cRoot = q.from(Customer.class);
Subquery<Customer> sq = q.subquery(Customer.class);
Root<Address> sqRoot = sq.from(Address.class);

q.where(cRoot.in(sq.select(sqRoot.get("customer"))));

q.select(cRoot);

em.createQuery(q).getResultList()

As I also mentioned earlier in the comments, the JPA specification only talks about "a list of values" with regard to IN, so either it doesn't assume support for IN with subquery, or takes for granted that it should work if you only pass one value, and that value is a subquery expression. So, it might be that the fact it worked in Hibernate 5 was non-compliant, or the changes they made in Hibernate 6 accidentally broke things for Firebird, because of the inflexibility of the parser of Firebird on this point.
In any case, rewriting to use EXISTS instead of IN can make it work within the JPA API, without having to resort to casting to the Hibernate-specific API:
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> q = cb.createQuery();
Root<Customer> cRoot = q.from(Customer.class);
Subquery<Customer> sq = q.subquery(Customer.class);
Root<Address> sqRoot = sq.from(Address.class);

sq.where(cb.equal(sqRoot.get("customer"), cRoot));
q.where(cb.exists(sq));

q.select(cRoot);

em.createQuery(q).getResultList();


For the reproduction, I used the following dummy classes:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CUSTOMER_ID_FK"))
    private Customer customer;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    protected Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

